# Node.js: SIGINT sent from process.kill() can't be handled

Tags: python, windows, node.js, sigint

I'm using Node.js v0.10.31 on Windows 8.1 x64. I noticed that for a process (a node.js or python script) that handles the `SIGINT` handler, the handler is not called when the signal is sent from another node.js process by `process.kill(PID, "SIGINT")`, and thus causing it to terminate. However I indeed verified that the handlers are called if the SIGINT is sent by pressing `CTRL-C` in console.

Here's the Node.js script that handles `SIGINT` (CoffeeScript):

```
process.on 'SIGINT', -> console.log "SIGINT handled"
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout)
console.log "PID: #{process.pid}"
```

Console Output:

```
PID: 6916
SIGINT handled        (this happens when pressing ctrl-c in console)
SIGINT handled        (this happens when pressing ctrl-c in console)
# process terminates when another process calls process.kill(6916, 'SIGINT')
```

And here's a python script that handles `SIGINT`, which is also killed unconditionally by node.js `process.kill(PID, 'SIGINT')`:

```
from signal import signal, SIGINT
import os
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
    print "signal handled:", signum,
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

signal(SIGINT, handler)

print "PID: ", os.getpid()
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1e6)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print " KeyboardInterrupt handled"
```

Console output:

```
PID:  6440
signal handled:2 KeyboardInterrupt handled    (this happens when pressing ctrl-c in console)
signal handled:2 KeyboardInterrupt handled    (this happens when pressing ctrl-c in console)
# process terminated by another node.js script's process.kill(6440, 'SIGINT')
```

Why isn't the handler called?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it's not the problem of Node.js that sends `SIGINT`, but rather a Windows platform issue. That's because when I send `SIGINT` from a python program, it also unconditionally terminates the process that handles the `SIGINT` event:

```
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Luckily Python documents this better:

> os.kill(pid, sig)
>
> Send signal sig to the process pid. Constants for
>   the specific signals available on the host platform are defined in the
>   signal module.
>
> Windows: The signal.CTRL_C_EVENT and signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT signals
>   are special signals which can only be sent to console processes which
>   share a common console window, e.g., some subprocesses. **Any other
>   value for sig will cause the process to be unconditionally killed by
>   the TerminateProcess API, and the exit code will be set to sig.** The
>   Windows version of kill() additionally takes process handles to be
>   killed.

Comment: The underlying problem IMO is that Node.js and Python are trying to pretend that signals are a universal concept, rather than one specific to particular operating systems.  It would probably be less confusing to the developer if the signal-related functions simply didn't exist in the Windows version, rather than existing but not behaving as expected.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Signals (at least SIGINT and some others) _are_ universal concept. These are [defined in the C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling) and should be supported by any plaftform.

Comment: C signals and UNIX signals aren't really the same thing.  In particular, the C standard doesn't appear to require any sort of support for sending signals between processes, and indeed the Visual Studio implementation doesn't allow you to do so.  (In UNIX, C signals are implemented using UNIX signals, and historically C signals were derived from UNIX signals, but conceptually they're distinct.)

Comment: Granted, by analogy to C, there's perhaps no reason not to implement signal() and raise() on Windows if they would be useful, though that sort of programming is kind of dated.  I still think implementing kill() was a mistake.  (For that matter, I think including signal and raise in the C standard library was a mistake, but if so it's one we're stuck with.)