# Control executed programm with python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I want to execute a testrun via bash, if the test needs too much time. So far, I found some good solutions here. But since the command kill does not work properly (when I use it correctly it says it is not used correctly), I decided to solve this problem using python. This is the Execution call I want to monitor:

```
EXE="C:/program.exe"
FILE="file.tpt"
HOME_DIR="C:/Home"


"$EXE" -vm-Xmx4096M --run build "$HOME_DIR/test/$FILE" "Auslieferung (ML) Execute"
```

(The opened *.exe starts a testrun which includes some simulink simulation runs - sometimes there are simulink errors - in this case, the execution time of the tests need too long and I want to restart the entire process).

First, I came up with the idea, calling a shell script containing these lines within a subprocess from python:

```
import subprocess
import time

process = subprocess.Popen('subprocess.sh', shell = True)
time.sleep(10)
process.terminate()
```

But when I use this, *.terminate() or *.kill() does not close the program I started with the subprocess call.

That´s why I am now trying to implement the entire call in python language. I got the following so far:

```
import subprocess

file = "somePath/file.tpt"

p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/program.exe", file])
```

Now I need to know, how to implement the second call "Auslieferung (ML) Execute" of the bash function. This call starts an intern testrun named "Auslieferung (ML) Execute". Any ideas? Or is it better to choose one of the other ways? Or can I get the "kill" option for bash somewhere, somehow?

Comment: It's it just another command line argument? Just append the string to the list.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061814/signal-handling-in-windows

Comment: @SimonHibbs I already tried that, it does not work